# How to get BearerTokenAuthentication from SecurityContext in a GlobalFilter in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Cloud Gateway as a OAuth2ResourceServer with following Authorisation Config:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
            exchanges
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
    return http.build();
}
```

I have a global filter in place which is responsible for performing some functions at each valid authenticated request, something like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomGlobal implements GlobalFilter {

    @Autowired
    BearerTokenAuthentication authentication;
    
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        // access request headers, and perform some logic

        // extract details from the JWT token, and perform some logic
        log.info(authentication.getTokenAttributes.get("sub")); 

        // ^ in the above line there's a NullPointerException, since instance 
        // BearerTokenAuthentication is not set, or not visible at a GlobalFilter class
        

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

I am still in a learning phase. Any possible leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did that this way(Note you should change WebFilter to GlobalFilter).

Add into your pom

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then Filter should be like

```
package filter;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Log4j2
public class CustomGlobal implements WebFilter {
    public static final String HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    private final ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public ReactiveJwtDecoder createDecoder(String issuer, String jwkUrl) {
        var jwtDecoder = NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUrl).build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(
                new JwtIssuerValidator(issuer),
                new JwtTimestampValidator()));
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    protected CustomGlobal(String issuer, String jwkUrl) {
        this.jwtDecoder = createDecoder(issuer, jwkUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono
                .defer(() -> {
                    var token = resolveToken(exchange.getRequest());
                    if (!StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
                        throw new BadJwtException("Authorisation token is invalid");
                    }
                    return jwtDecoder.decode(token);
                })
                .flatMap(tokenJwt -> {
                    log.info(tokenJwt.getClaimAsString("sub"));
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                })
                .onErrorResume(err -> handleError(exchange));
    }


    private Mono<Void> handleError(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        exchange.getResponse().setRawStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }

    private String resolveToken(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(HEADER_PREFIX)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7).trim();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Next step would be to create configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;


@Configuration
public class CustomGlobalConfig {
    @Value("${jwt.iss}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${jwt.jwk-uri}")
    private String jwkUrl;


    @Bean
    CustomGlobal createFilterBean() {
        return new CustomGlobal(this.issuer, this.jwkUrl);
    }

}
```